# Which Continuous Integration service should I choose for average Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Our project has 4 developers, but we have a lot of Rspec tests: they take 30 minutes in one thread.
Comfortable count of threads for one build is 3. Also we follow agile methodology and there are few simultaneous commits at Friday’s afternoon. Waiting in the queue is not what we want. So our team wants to run 2 builds (each in 3 threads) simultaneously: 6 threads as a result. As I understood, at [Travis](https://travis-ci.com/) we need to pay at least $250 - it’s not so pleasant.
Also I read about [Vexor.io](https://vexor.io/) - new CI service with unlimited number of parallel threads. As I understood, with Vexor you need to pay only for minutes of testing. It's an unpopular service, so I'm afraid of using it. Did anybody try [Vexor](https://vexor.io/)? Which price can we expect?
Or you could advice some other CI with which we could:

1. Avoid standing in the queue.
2. Test in 3 (at least) threads.
3. Don’t pay for this big money.

Comment: JoelL, how much simultaneous builds could Drone run?

Comment: Your question is asking for opinions and/or recommendations, both of which are off-topic.

Comment: You can try Semaphore (https://semaphoreci.com/).
Disclaimer: i work there, so feel free to ask anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Vexor and it left good impression. Take a closer look at it, because:

1. Vexor really allows you to run as much threads as you want.
2. As I remember, it has some free minutes each month, so you can try it for free.
3. Vexor is compatible with `.travis.yml`.
4. We had a similar by size project and price was less than 50$.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try anything but Travis (if we talk about SaaS). But you can try some self-hosted solution like Jenkins. You can customize it as you want, also you’ll achieve a lower price.

Comment: Thanks! But we are looking for SaaS solution. We haven't time and people to manage a self-hosted variant.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/). I've been using it for a while, it's really easy to set up and use, and it is also very flexible in terms of configuration. And their staff is very helpful too, I get answers to all my questions within 12 hours.

Here's the link to their docs section about [parallelism](https://circleci.com/docs/parallelism).

Comment: Yes, CircleCI is good. But to have possibility to run 2 concurrent builds with 4x parallelism we need to pay 350$ - not so cheap. 
And It's also unpleasant that we'll take this power only few times a week. In other time CircleCI will just idle and spend our money.
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2mo60iu.jpg